# Remote Desktop into Ubuntu from Laptop

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, home-networking

I was wondering what I need to do to be able to access my desktop through remote desktop from my laptop.

They are both running Ubuntu and are using the same internet connection. I do not have a static IP. I don't know if I need to set up a home network to be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu "Main Menu" there is smth like System -> Preferences -> Remote Desktop . There you can check the box saying that remote connections are allowed, put password etc.

I use such remote desktop over VNC protocol from Windows machine, but I believe it's even easier to access it from other Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have X11 forwarding configured, don't mind starting a new session, and know the host/machine name then it should be easy.

```
ssh -X machinename
gnome-panel
```

X tunnels tend to be fast as heck over a local network.  For remote connections you will notice a noticeable speed decrease.

Also there is vino (a vnc server) included with gnome, which takes just a few moments to configure.  I don't have an install available to me ATM but I believe it was in the preferences under remote access or something.

Comment: You can also run `vino-preferences` if you're too lazy to look through the menus, like me :)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try that. I was hoping to have access to both my laptop & the remote session so the VNC option seems better.

Comment: if both are running ubuntu, and you don't need the full remote desktop, you could easily run individual programs and have them display on the laptop's Xserver.  that's what this solution does: you get the laptop's main session, and the remote apps aren't confined to a VNC client window.  what you don't get is the desktop's main session.